# Google authentication in php/laravel error: Error: invalid_request Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to build a simple authentication system in my php/laravel app with Google auth using Socialite package, based on [this post](https://medium.com/justlaravel/laravel-social-login-using-socialite-45305c7ddc00), but I'm getting the following error on the browser:

[image]

my google console credentials are configured like this

[image]

and I get this error when I try to login using google, accessing the route '/redirect/google/'
I've been searching for two days, but I haven't found any results containing 'missing authority'.
what does missing authority mean? and how to fix this error?

Comment: Your `redirect_uri` needs to be a whole URL, i.e. starting with something like `http://` like it does in your GCP console.

Answer (score 0):

Under **"Authorized Redirect URIs"**, there is mention that the URL not contain relative paths. You would have to redirect directly to `localhost:8000`, not `localhost:8000/callback/google/`  ..

If you need to be at the relative path, then make your callback endpoint do whatever it needs to do at `localhost:8000`, then from there have it itself handle any further redirection.

Comment: Absolute paths like `https://localhost:8000/callback/google` are fine. "No relative paths" means you can't put in something like plain old `callback/google`.

Comment: Maybe so, but I had a similar problem and it was only fixed by redirecting to the base of the URL, specifically at `http://127.0.0.1/ `. I handled the Google code outside of the application directory then redirected.

Comment: I've used non-root redirect URIs on a regular basis. They work fine.

Comment: Good to know. For next time.